# How to find the rotation of one object relative to the local axes of another?

Tags: python

I have a series of objects that can be though of as a chain made of individual links. I am using a python script to place and orient these objects onto the surface of a mesh. This is working well.

Here is where I am stuck: I am trying to get the rotation of each 'link' relative to the previous links local axes in the same script. More specifically and in reference to the image below, the final output I am looking for is an XZY Euler that gives the rotations to get from object 1 to object 2 using the local axes of object 1. Said another way, I am looking for the local XZY rotations that will align the rotation of 1 with that of 2 without actually applying the rotation to the object.

[image]

My current thoughts are that I need to get the rotation matrix of object 1, then calculate a change of basis matrix to go back to the world coordinates (similar to clearing the rotation with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> just without actually rotating the object in the 3d view). Then I can multiply this matrix by the rotation matrix of object 2 and convert that to an Euler since I don't know of a way to convert to an Euler using local axes.

Would this work, and is there an easier way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but did you try `(ob1.matrix_world.inverted() @ ob2.matrix_world).to_euler(...)`

Comment: You're not missing anything, that does it! I had tried something similar before but I didn't realise that you use @ to multiply matrices. If you put this as an answer I will happily award the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the relative matrix of `child` in regards to `parent` do

```
mat_rel = parent.matrix_world.inverted() @ child.matrix_world
```

To convert a matrix's rotation to euler notation use [`to_euler`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.to_euler).

```
euler_rel = mat_rel.to_euler('XYZ')
```